# Leveling hip pelvis after squat un rack

Tags: squats

In 2:43 of [this video](https://youtu.be/gcNh17Ckjgg?t=163) by Jeremy Ethier, it is said to level hip pelvis after squat unrack. What is the idea behind this?

Some sites I've seen that we should start the squat by sitting back a bit, so I don't get what the idea behind leveling is, if we are going to sit back a bit at the end anyways.